# wrap text to a certain column size using bash printf command

Tags: linux, bash

How to get the following output using printf command?

```
$ drive=/test1/test2/test3/test4
$ echo $drive | fold -10
/test1/tes
t2/test3/t
est4
```

Comment: with `printf` you can print the 10 first characters of a string, but for the rest you'll have to manipulate the string.

Comment: Why do you want to use `printf` specifically? Do you actually want to use only builtins? In that case, `printf` shouldn't be necessary. You can [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: `using printf command?` Do you want to use _only_ printf? or just `printf "%s\n" "$(echo $drive | fold -10)"`?

Comment: Hi thanks its solve my issue :)